# ListView in Android: use simple_selectable_list_item

Tags: android, listview

Within Android Studio, I try to create *ListView*, and selecting an item (highlighting with other colour, usually blue) is needed. Layout *simple_list_item_single_choice* works, but it isn't exactly what I'd like to have. More promising is *simple_selectable_list_item*, but it doesn't work: items isn't shown at all. There is fragment of code:

```
ArrayAdapter<MyTimerTask> adapterTasks = new ArrayAdapter<MyTimerTask>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
ListView listTasks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTasks);
listTasks.setAdapter(adapterTasks);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? If you want something specific, you could create your own layout for the row, and use a custom Adapter for it. If you can specify what you're looking for, somebody might be able to help.

Comment: Rachit, thanks for quick reply.
I'd like to have simple list (not drop-dwon combo) with possibility to select an item. Analogue in Delphi is TListBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think u just don't load your array:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,**yourArrayList**); //you forgot to load your List I think
        listTasks.setAdapter(adapter);
        listTasks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { //here u can use clickListener
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true); 
      }
});
```

If you still need help you can worked with this Tutorial. It explains perfectly (for me):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nZMoBjq6Qg&index=17&list=PLshdtb5UWjSp0879mLeCsDQN6L73XBZTk

There are also 4 other tutorials in his playlist. (for different problems/solutions)

Comment: MrOrhan, thanks for reply. I create empty list, then user can add item. Layout **simple_list_item_1** works (as well as some other layout), but simple_selectable_list_item (as well as some others) doesn't.
Thanks for advising to colour selected item manually; I thought there should be direct way (similar to Windows listbox), but might be there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody who tried to help. I am now realizing that in Android system there isn't native behaviour of list to highlight selected item. The only thing that could be advised is to paint item manually by setting listener on 'select item event'. About simple_selectable_list_item, I've managed to get it working, but without selecting item. Now my decision is to use layout *simple_list_item_multiple_choice*, this approach is typical for Android devices.